# Select dynamic range in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel table, and a form control (button) which select specific data from the table and copy it into mail. I would like to know how can I select only some columns from the table, not all of the columns?

Please your assistance, Thanks

Here is part of my code:

```
Sub SendCA_list()

Call FilterCA 'filter the table per specific data

Range("Table4[[#Headers],[Department]]").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select 'select all the columns after the column 'department'- how to select only 10 columns?
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-129
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: You could try : Range(Table Name & "[[Column Start]:[Column End]]").Select

Comment: @Error1004 Thanks, i tried this line: `Range("Table4[[Department]:[Status]]").Select` and it is working and provide selecting the required data in the table, but i need also the Headers, do you know how to select them to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ShiraL try ti import [#All] before the columns name:

```
Range("Table4[[#All],[Department]:[Status]]").Select
```

Answer (score 2):

You [don't need to select anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683).

```
Range("Table4[[#All],[Column1]],Table4[[#All],[Column2]],Table4[[#All],[Column4]]").Copy
```

Comment: Thanks @GSerg. I have many column to copy, so writing each of them is not the most inefficient way.. `Range("Table4[[Department]:[Status]]").Select` - this code work fine but without the headers, do you know how can i select them to?.

Comment: @ShiraL. `Range("Table4[[#All],[Department]:[Status]]").Select`